# Android Google maps ошибка получения пути

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Хочу проложить маршрут между двумя точками
Но выкидывает ошибку, хотя PostMan выдает результат. В чем ошибка?

```
public void showRoute(LatLng myPosition, LatLng shopId){

        from = ""+myPosition.latitude+","+myPosition.longitude;
        to = ""+shopId.latitude+","+shopId.longitude;
        Log.e("from",String.valueOf(from));
        Log.e("to",String.valueOf(to));


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

                .build();
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        service.getRoute(from, to, true, "ru", new Callback<RouteResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RouteResponse> call, Response<RouteResponse> response) {
                //Декодируем маршрут в точки LatLng
                List<LatLng> mPoints = PolyUtil.decode(response.body().getPoints());
                //Строим полилинию
                PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                polylineOptions.width(4f).color(R.color.colorPrimary);
                LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for(int i = 0;i<mPoints.size();i++){
                    polylineOptions.add((LatLng)mPoints.get(i));
                    latLngBuilder.include((LatLng)mPoints.get(i));
                }
                map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                int size = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                LatLngBounds latLngBounds = latLngBuilder.build();
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds,size,size,25);
                map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
//
                //
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RouteResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Ошибку кидает на строчку `service.getRoute(from, to, true, "ru", new Callback<RouteResponse>() {`

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class com.example.danilshik.testapplication.models.RouteResponse
                      for method APIService.getRoute
                      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:751)
                      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:236)
                      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:161)
                      at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:169)
                      at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:146)
                      at $Proxy1.getRoute(Native Method)
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.fragments.ShopInMapWay.showRoute(ShopInMapWay.java:163)
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.fragments.ShopInMapWay.onMapReady(ShopInMapWay.java:130)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
                      at fs.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685005@12.6.85 (000700-197041431):20)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685005@12.6.85 (000700-197041431):5)
                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685005@12.6.85 (000700-197041431):5)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class com.example.danilshik.testapplication.models.RouteResponse.
                    Tried:
                     * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
                      at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:240)
                      at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:204)
                      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:234)
                        ... 22 more
```

Класс

```
public class RouteResponse {
    public List<Route> routes;

    public String getPoints(){
        return this.routes.get(0).overviewPolyline.points;
    }
    class Route{
        OverviewPolyline overviewPolyline;
    }
    class OverviewPolyline{
        String points;
    }
}
```

JSON, который приходит в PostMan

```
{
    "geocoded_waypoints": [
        {
            "geocoder_status": "OK",
            "place_id": "ChIJs4CrATw62UMRKg9NqObeA2I",
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        },
        {
            "geocoder_status": "OK",
            "place_id": "ChIJcQYIThU62UMRmhKGs-q_q70",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "bounds": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 54.7380729,
                    "lng": 55.9732509
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 54.7329662,
                    "lng": 55.9581493
                }
            },
            "copyrights": "Картографические данные © 2018 Google",
            "legs": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "1,7 км",
                        "value": 1690
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "8 мин.",
                        "value": 470
                    },
                    "end_address": "ул. Ивана Якутова, Уфа, Респ. Башкортостан, Россия",
                    "end_location": {
                        "lat": 54.73732889999999,
                        "lng": 55.9581493
                    },
                    "start_address": "ул. Мингажева, 160/1, Уфа, Респ. Башкортостан, Россия, 450005",
                    "start_location": {
                        "lat": 54.7348831,
                        "lng": 55.9732509
                    },
                    "steps": [
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "20 м",
                                "value": 20
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 6
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7347061,
                                "lng": 55.9732059
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Направляйтесь на <b>юг</b>",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "_lamIygstI`@F"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7348831,
                                "lng": 55.9732509
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "67 м",
                                "value": 67
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 36
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73477699999999,
                                "lng": 55.972175
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>направо</b> в сторону <b>ул. Мингажева</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "}jamIqgstIEjBG`B"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7347061,
                                "lng": 55.9732059
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "91 м",
                                "value": 91
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 46
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.734899,
                                "lng": 55.9708943
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>налево</b> в сторону <b>ул. Мингажева</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-left",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "kkamIcastIB@DB@@@@?B@@?H?D?FAJQvAI|@Iv@"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73477699999999,
                                "lng": 55.972175
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,2 км",
                                "value": 223
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 64
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7329662,
                                "lng": 55.9699862
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>налево</b> на <b>ул. Мингажева</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-left",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "clamIayrtIn@RLFdCv@xB~@bA^"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.734899,
                                "lng": 55.9708943
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,8 км",
                                "value": 758
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "2 мин.",
                                "value": 141
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7349762,
                                "lng": 55.9589906
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>направо</b> на <b>ул. Революционная</b>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "a`amImsrtIAf@OfACb@SpBc@pGG`AI~@Ef@a@hFKrAOvBI|@QhBALIz@]rDKnAe@`FKxCIdAOXINIJCBSTA??@KHUJ"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7329662,
                                "lng": 55.9699862
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,4 км",
                                "value": 369
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "2 мин.",
                                "value": 99
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7380729,
                                "lng": 55.9594288
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "На круге сверните на <b>2-й</b> съезд на <b>ул. Цюрупы</b>",
                            "maneuver": "roundabout-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "slamIunptICCAACAG?GAG@G@MFCBABCFCNAHAJo@d@OTICSEwE}Ai@SOEoA]KE}@[UI"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7349762,
                                "lng": 55.9589906
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "0,1 км",
                                "value": 101
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 31
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73719089999999,
                                "lng": 55.9590615
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Выполните <b>разворот</b>",
                            "maneuver": "uturn-left",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "}_bmImqptITH|@ZJDnA\\"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.7380729,
                                "lng": 55.9594288
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance": {
                                "text": "61 м",
                                "value": 61
                            },
                            "duration": {
                                "text": "1 мин.",
                                "value": 47
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73732889999999,
                                "lng": 55.9581493
                            },
                            "html_instructions": "Поверните <b>направо</b> на <b>ул. Ивана Якутова</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Пункт назначения будет слева</div>",
                            "maneuver": "turn-right",
                            "polyline": {
                                "points": "mzamIcoptI[tD"
                            },
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 54.73719089999999,
                                "lng": 55.9590615
                            },
                            "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                        }
                    ],
                    "traffic_speed_entry": [],
                    "via_waypoint": []
                }
            ],
            "overview_polyline": {
                "points": "_lamIygstI`@FEjBG`BB@FD@D@Xg@xE|@ZdCv@xB~@bA^Af@SjBw@bKQ`CcA|Mg@pFi@bGe@`FKxCIdAOXSZYZa@TEE[AUHEFGVCTo@d@OT]IaGqB_Bc@iAa@UITHhA`@nA\\[tD"
            },
            "summary": "ул. Революционная",
            "warnings": [],
            "waypoint_order": []
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Статья, по которой делал: https://habr.com/post/275019/

Upd APIService:

```
@GET ("maps/api/direction/json")
    RouteResponse getRoute(
            @Query(value = "origin", encoded = false) String position,
            @Query(value = "destination",encoded = false) String dectination,
            @Query("sensor") boolean sensor,
            @Query("language") String language,
            Callback<RouteResponse> cb
    );
```

Comment: Нужен еще класс APIService.
Большая вероятность что ошибка именно в нем.

Comment: Добавил, ниже вопроса

Comment: А если попробовать в этом классе для метода возвращать Call<RouteResponse>?

Comment: error: incompatible types: <anonymous Callback<RouteResponse>> cannot be converted to Call<RouteResponse>

Comment: это начало выдавать когда изменил APIService

Answer (score 0):

Побробуйте добавить аннотации к моделям, чтобы парсер мог понять как матчить поля в ответе:

```
public class DirectionResults {
@SerializedName("routes")
private List<Route> routes;

public List<Route> getRoutes() {
    return routes;
}}
 public class Route {
@SerializedName("overview_polyline")
private OverviewPolyLine overviewPolyLine;

private List<Legs> legs;

public OverviewPolyLine getOverviewPolyLine() {
    return overviewPolyLine;
}

public List<Legs> getLegs() {
    return legs;
}
}

public class Legs {
private List<Steps> steps;

public List<Steps> getSteps() {
    return steps;
}
}

public class Steps {
private Location start_location;
private Location end_location;
private OverviewPolyLine polyline;

public Location getStart_location() {
    return start_location;
}

public Location getEnd_location() {
    return end_location;
}

public OverviewPolyLine getPolyline() {
    return polyline;
}
}

public class OverviewPolyLine {

@SerializedName("points")
public String points;

public String getPoints() {
    return points;
}
}

public class Location {
private double lat;
private double lng;

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public double getLng() {
    return lng;
}
}
```

Отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/30184220/5892568 + там в ответах есть untility для работы.

Comment: вы думаете в этом ошибке? почему тогда у автора статьи работает. Да он использовал более старую версию, я код обновил под новую версию. Думаю, что что-то при обновлении не то сделал

Comment: Теперь вы можете декодировать и закодировать путь, используя PolyUtils.decode () в «Утилите API Google Maps Android API.
Я вот и использую его в List<LatLng> mPoints = PolyUtil.decode(response.body().getPoints());